# Modifying jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using the following plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/dynamic-step-process-panels/118950
and I am trying to modify its behavior. Currently when the last tab is reached the next button becomes inactive, its class is changed from 'button activeButton' to 'button inactiveButton'. I need to change the next buttons class to one which I create myself, which will act as a submit button.

I have unsuccessfully tried to modify the div class in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#processPanel").processPanel({
            kind: "freeChoice",
            icons: true,
            nextPrevButtons: true,
            style: "green-blue",
            afterOpen: function(event, step, content, stepNumber){
                if(stepNumber==3)
                {
                    $(".button inactiveButton").attr('class', 'button activeButton-green-blue');
                }
            }
        });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Try using the "onOpen" event handler instead of afterOpen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a single element with multiple classes, prepend each with a period and leave out the space:

```
$(".button.inactiveButton")...
```

With the space and `inactiveButton` not having a prefix, the selector is trying to match something like this:

```
<div class="button">
    <inactiveButton />
</div>
```

---

You may also look at using [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) rather than setting the `class` attribute directly:

```
$(".button.inactiveButton")
    .removeClass('inactiveButton')
    .addClass('activeButton-green-blue');
```

This way, if the element has any other classes assigned to it, you won't remove them unintentionally.

Comment: I gave the altered button a title of 'Submit'and I am trying unsuccessfully to have it submit the form.

$("[title='Submit']").click(function(){
   alert('submit!');
     $("#RoomAddForm").submit();
    });

any advice?

Comment: @CroninO'M Make sure that the button is available when binding `.click`: `alert($('[title="Submit"]').size());` But, you may have to use delegated binding with either [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/): `$('#RoomAddForm').on('click', '[title="Submit"]', function () { /* ... */ });`

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. The element i'm binding the 'click' to doesn't exist on document load, so this is why it's failing?
I tried your suggestion but I'm getting error:$("#RoomAddForm").on is not a function

Comment: @CroninO'M What version of jQuery are you using? `.on` was added with 1.7 and `.delegate` with 1.4.2. But, yeah - event binding only works with elements that exist at that moment. Delegation works by taking advantage of event bubbling to have an existing ancestor capture the event for a descendant that may or may not exist yet.

Comment: Got the Submit functionality working, thanks @Jonathan Lonowski. Turs out my form wasn't structured properly. I gave the submit button an id of 'sub' and the following code worked:
$("#RoomAddForm").delegate("#sub", "click", function() {
    $("#RoomAddForm").submit();  
   });

Thanks again...